# Counting Years and Months of rows in a table - conflict of scripts

Tags: sql, date, count, range, rows

Im trying to count how many rows in a table by month and year.
Then getting the rows to examine for that time period but my scripts are way out in numbers
First - get all rows split into months

```
SELECT    COUNT(*) 
FROM      EmailSends 
WHERE     YEAR(CreateDate) = '2020' 
GROUP BY  MONTH(CreateDate)
```

gives me an output of

```
    (No column name)
24967  <-January
37251
13897
7498
12052
79943
26146
4340
4961
75797
17340
17653
```

then I run the below expecting 24967 rows but get 79,943 but the date range is good from the results. (Jan 1-31 2020)

```
SELECT    EmailID,CreateDate,Subject
FROM      Emailsends
WHERE     MONTH (createdate) = '1' and YEAR(CreateDate) = '2020'
GROUP BY  Emailsends.CreateDate,Emailsends.EmailID ,MONTH(CreateDate),Emailsends.Subject
```

.

```
select * from Emailsends where CreateDate between '2020-01-01 00:00:00.001' and '2020-02-01 00:00:00.001'
```

also returns 79943

Can you help? - unsure what I'm doing wrong. - Looks like the count script isn't playing or there's something else being counted that the count script isn't.

Comment: What does your first query yield if you do `WHERE YEAR(CreateDate) = 2020 AND MONTH(CreateDate) = 1`...?

Comment: @Stu result is 79943 , thanks.

Comment: so does that clear it up for you?

Comment: @Stu yeah it does Stu , The select count (*) should be returning 79943 but only gives 24967 - do you know why this would be?